# Query conversation message Enhanced whatsapp

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, query, digital-engagement, whatsapp

Previously on the standard version we can do query to get message body using :

> SELECT Id, ActorType, ActorId, ActorName, Message FROM ConversationEntry WHERE ConversationId = '0MXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

With enhanced whatsapp DE, it shows record of ConversationEntry but all message fields has blank value. So how to get the message with Enhanced Whatsapp Digital Engagement?

Comment: As a current DE user I've not heard of, nor been able to find anything, on enhanced WhatsApp. Is it a pilot/beta? I only ask as I suspect there will not be many (except Salesforce) who could answer this today.

Comment: Hi it's already Generally Available since 18 March, you are able to add enhanced whatsapp from messaging setting directly without whatsapp enablement team as long you have facebook business account with role admin. @Girbot

Comment: I can't find any option, do you have a link to any documentation for it? I'm happy to try to help if I can replicate :)

Comment: @Girbot this is the article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_service_enhanced_whatsapp.htm&release=242&type=5. If you want to try, go setup->messaging setting->new->whatsapp->choose enhanced-> continue the rest